# alter table code in android...

Tags: android, sqlite

following is the code that i used to alter my table but my app is crashing.

I have create this `dbupdateadapter` class separately. the records are being added, but the column is not added to the same table

```
public class dbupdateadapter {
    public static final String TABLE_MEMBERID="memberid";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="myfemmefab.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME="registeration";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=2;

    private static final String DATABASE_UPDATE="ALTER TABLE registeration ADD COLUMN(memberid TEXT);";

    private static Context context1;

    private dbhelper1 helper1;
    private SQLiteDatabase sdb1;

    public dbupdateadapter(Context con){
    this.context1=con;
helper1=new dbhelper1(context1);
 }
public class dbhelper1 extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
 public dbhelper1(Context context){
     super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
 }
 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb1){
     sdb1.execSQL(DATABASE_UPDATE);
 }
 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sdb1,int oldver,int newver){
        //android.util.Log.w("constants", "upgrading database will destroy the old data");
    if(newver>oldver){
        sdb1.execSQL(DATABASE_UPDATE);  
    }

        //onCreate(sdb1);
    }
 }
 public dbupdateadapter open() throws SQLException{
 sdb1=helper1.getWritableDatabase();
 return this;
}
void insertcoldata (String memberid){
 ContentValues cv1=new ContentValues();
 cv1.put(TABLE_MEMBERID, memberid);
 sdb1.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv1);
}
public void close(){
 helper1.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `"ALTER TABLE registeration ADD memberid TEXT;";` or `"ALTER TABLE registeration ADD COLUMN memberid TEXT;";` You have an error in syntax.

Where are you creating yout table? You are executing `DATABASE_UPDATE` in your `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that in

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db ){ ... }
```

you should create your `tables` and populate them with some *initial values* and you didn't create table in your snippet of code.

for **upgrating** your tables you should use

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { ... }
```

Exactly from docs:

> Called when the database needs to be upgraded. The implementation
>   should use this method to drop tables, add tables, or do anything else
>   it needs to upgrade to the new schema version.

Also have look at

- [`SQL As Understood By
  SQLite`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)
- [`Example of how to implement ALTER
  TABLE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632282/example-of-how-to-implement-alter-table)